# Any need to verify disks after hard reboot?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, crash

About every few days I need to reboot my 2012 MacBook Pro Retina.

I noticed these messages in the logs regarding "Journal is read-only and journal is dirty. Can not mount volume".

Any need to "Verify Disk" in Disk Utilities?

[image]

Comment: Never hurts trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X doesn't normally seem to repair drives or volumes after hard resets or kernel panics, or at least [the verbose startup output looks the same](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88604/how-to-auto-run-disk-repair-on-os-x-after-each-system-crash/88676#88676), and you don't probably need to do that manually either.

In this case you could try verifying the drives or volumes (logical partitions) as troubleshooting steps though. Note that the Verify Disk button performs completely different operations depending on whether a drive or a volume is selected. HFS+ volumes that support live verification can be verified even when they are mounted as the root filesystem, but you have to start up from the recovery partition to repair them.

According to [Apple KB article TS1417](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1417), running `fsck` is not usually necessary.